# save setting in android app

Tags: android, settings

I have an app that shows some items and buttons. The user can hide any of these buttons or items. In the settings the user can delete button 1:

```
case R.id.action_delete:
    button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);       
    return false;
```

It works fine, but the problem is that when the user restarts the app, button 1 will be there again.

Comment: Google `SharedPreferences Android` to learn more about this. You'll need to save the settings when they are set, and then read them and apply them in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Prefs";


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
if (settings.getString("button", "").toString().equals("button")) {
button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}



case R.id.action_delete:
     button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
     editor.putString("button", "button");
     editor.commit();  
     return false;
```

Comment: how can i save the settings on shared preferences can you please write it for me 
and the code on oncreate how i write it . sorry am new to android app plzz i need it

Comment: Check the answer above, it should work like that, mark it as answer if it does work :)

Comment: have you added `public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Prefs";`???
Post your code here

Comment: Bro i love u its work 100% , but i would like to ask u something . i have Difficult to understand what is going on . if i want to add another save stat like if i have another button call button2 , should i write the code again but for button2 and if i have other then button like img or something i use also editor.putString(button" , "Button"); ,

Comment: I'm glad it worked :)
If you want to add more e.g if you want the button2 to go invisible too then your code will be like this:
`case R.id.action_delete:
     button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
     editor.putString("button", "button");
     editor.putString("button2", "hidden");
     editor.commit();  
     return false;`

instead of button you can name them whatever you want, first is the name, 2nd is the value you give it

Comment: and `onCreate` add this `if (settings.getString("button2", "").toString().equals("hidden")) {
button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
        }

Comment: thanks bro u so helpful for me .. everything is work But i try to move the Button to a setting activity but it dose not work have a look in my new Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565840/saving-setting-from-different-activity-android